# Pearson Product-Moment Correlation Coefficient Weighting in Python

Tags: python, pearson

I am currently using the following function to calculate the Pearson Product-Moment Correlation Coefficient in python.

```
def PearsonCoefficient(x, y):
  assert len(x) == len(y)
  n = len(x)
  assert n > 0
  avg_x = float(sum(x)) / n
  avg_y = float(sum(y)) / n
  diffprod = 0
  xdiff2 = 0
  ydiff2 = 0
  for idx in range(n):
    xdiff = x[idx] - avg_x
    ydiff = y[idx] - avg_y
    diffprod += xdiff * ydiff
    xdiff2 += xdiff * xdiff
    ydiff2 += ydiff * ydiff

  p = math.sqrt(xdiff2 * ydiff2)
  if p == 0:
    return None
  return diffprod / p
```

My data is time series based (on the x) with a y value indicating a user score. I am grouping the time series data by week and taking an average of the scores for that time period. However I would like to weight the last three months worth of data higher than previous data. I am unsure as to how I generate my weighting vector based on this assumption.

My data looks like

```
jan 1st  - 0.4
jan 8th  - 0.7
jan 15th - 0.55
jan 22nd - 0.75
jan 29th - 0.88
feb 5th  - 0.91
feb 12th - 0.87
feb 19th - 0.89
feb 26th - 0.93
feb 5th  - 0.56
...
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is in the `statsmodels` package:

```
pip install statsmodels
```

and then in python:

```
from statsmodels.stats.weightstats import DescrStatsW
...
```

There's an example on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11460876/420867) (note: the statsmodels bug referred to in that answer has been fixed).

Answer (score -1):

If you can use numpy, you can do something like

```
import numpy as np

def PearsonCoefficient(x, y):
    assert len(x) == len(y)
    assert len(x) > 0

    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)

    # Generate uniform weights
    w = np.ones(52)

    # Increase the weight of the last three months 
    w[-12:] = 1.5
    w /= np.sum(w)

    # Actual weighting
    x *= w
    y *= w

    # Calculate pearson correlation and return the result
    return np.corrcoef(x, y)
```

Comment: I cant find any documentation for divide assignment on lists in python. What exactly is the "/=" doing? My guess is a division on each element on the list by the sum of the weights?

Comment: w is a numpy array not a python list. And your guess is correct /= is a division on each element on the list.

Comment: You're multiplying the scores by the weights - this changes the actual measurement, not the strength of it's impact on the correlation.

Comment: DO NOT USE THAT SOLUTION! It is completely wrong... It multiplies values instead of changing the multiplicity!